# Why can't I import the Crypto module in python even with pycryptodome installed?

Tags: python, terminal, pycryptodome

I have run all commands in the terminal to clear any previous forms of crypto, but after I ran
"pip3 install pycryptodome" and it successfully installed, I still cannot import the "Crypto.Cipher" module. Can anyone help?

Comment: What happens when you try to import it? Are you installing it to the same environment that you're running code in?

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
pip3 uninstall crypto 
pip3 uninstall pycrypto 
pip3 install pycryptodome
```

All these packages get installed in the same folder so will overwrite files.